# Is it possible to use perl-like regular expressions with the linux find command?

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression

I would like to use find perl-style regular expressions when using the find command to search for files. Currently it doesn't seem like this is supported.

> valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’

Is there any way to add the perl regular expression engine to the find command?

I want to use it with find natively; I do not want to pipe the output of find to grep or another program.

Comment: No, not possible as a user. If you are developer, maybe try to fork `find` sources to include `PCRE`, but it seems a bit rude for one person.

Comment: You might want to ask a new question, explaining what you are trying to do. While find does not support PCREs, there are many things you can do with ERE or other regex flavors and you can also pass the output o `find` to tools that do support PCREs, so if you explain what the final objective is, we should be able to give you a solution.

Comment: The only way without pipe is to use `grep -P` in `find . -exec grep -P 're' {} +`

Comment: @GillesQuenot that would search through the contents of the files, not their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do it with find without rewriting find.

You requested no pipes, but it’s not possible without.

```
find . -print0 |
    perl -0ne 'print if /some perl regexp/s' | 
    xargs -r0 …
```

Where … is what you do with the files if just writing them to disk is insufficient.

Instead of `perl`, with GNU `grep`, you can also use `grep -zP` (or `grep --null -P` slightly more portable for `grep`s of some BSDs that are based on the API of an older version of GNU `grep`).

A closer equivalent to a hypothetical `find . -regextype perl -regex 'some perl regexp' -exec cmd {} +`, with shells with support for ksh-style process substitution would be:

```
xargs -r0a <(
  find . -print0 |
    perl -0ne 'print if /some perl regexp/s') cmd
```

Which like `-exec cmd {} +` preserves `cmd`'s stdin. Note that `<(...)` still uses pipes.

Note that by default, `perl` works byte-wise while `find`/`grep` tend to work character-wise. The `-C` or `-Mopen=locale` options can help decode bytes to characters before doing the matching.

Note that `-print0`, `-r`, `-0`, `-a`, `-z`, `-P`, `-regex`, `-regex-type` are all non-standard GNU extensions, with `-print0`/`-0` now found in most other implementations. `-r` (to not run the command if no file is found) is also common. `-regex` (not `-regex-type`) as well though the default regex syntax varies with the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

One way to use only one process, is to use only *pure Perl* with [`File::Find` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find).

It's included in the core since `perl5`, so you don't have anything to install:

```
$ corelist File::Find

Data for 2021-05-20
File::Find was first released with perl 5
```

There's a `find2perl` script [out there](https://metacpan.org/release/LEONT/App-find2perl-1.005/raw/script/find2perl?download=1).

You can generate the Perl code from your usual `find` commands:

```
find2perl [paths] [predicates]
```

Ex:

```
$ find2perl . -type f -name '*l'
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell

use strict;
use File::Find ();

# Set the variable $File::Find::dont_use_nlink if you're using AFS,
# since AFS cheats.

# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

sub wanted;
   
# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '.');
exit;

sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
    -f _ &&                 # -type f
    /^.*l\z/s               # ^.*l$ regex to modify as you want
    && print("$name\n");    # -print
}
```

Now you have a *base* to start working around. You can modify the Perl regex as you want with your own regex.

Usage:

```
find2perl -type f -name '*l' > myPerlFind.pl
chmod +x myPerlFind.pl
$EDITOR myPerlFind.pl
./myPerlFind.pl
```

---

You can also use `@ARGV` to pass arguments to your script or even better: [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Or rather, yes it is *possible*, but you need to program it yourself. Unless you find an implementation of `find` that supports [PCREs](http://www.pcre.org/), and I personally don't know of one, your only choice is to code it yourself.

If a program you use doesn't have a feature you need, your only option is to ask the developers to implement it and hope they do, or to code it yourself. Since most of us don't have the necessary knowledge to go and extend the capabilities of a tool like `find`, I fear the answer to your question is basically "no".

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the globs of `zsh`, which have most of the features of `find` (and features not found in any `find` implementation) can do PCRE matching via the `e` glob qualifier:

```
set -o rematchpcre
print -rC1 -- **/*(NDe['[[ $REPLY =~ "some perl regexp" ]]'])
```

To `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn the files whose path matches the perl-like regular expression. Replace `$REPLY` with `$REPLY:t` to only match on the file's base name (`t`ail) instead of full path.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this works (the regex matches not just the filename, but the full path):

```
find tmp/ -regex '.*pack.ge.jso.$'
```

Comment: While that's a valid Perl regex, it's also a valid POSIX basic (or extended) regex. It doesn't use any features specific to _Perl regexes_, so it hardly shows anything about them.